# Can we get rid of the disclosure triangles that don't disclose anything on the edit screen?

Tags: feature-request, edits, design, editor

I can't count the number of times I've tried to click one of these triangles:

[image: edit-screen-screenshot]

Could we change them to something more... non-clickable? Like these little things: ● ● ● ●?

[image: possible-alternative]

Comment: @random And they succeed. Three times apiece.

Comment: @Dukeling That's great, unless you happen to be suffering from short-term memory loss, bad eyesight, and short-term memory loss.

Comment: @Undo which is a pretty rare combination, in my opinion.

Comment: Here's a workaround for you: `$('.dingus').html('&bull;').css('font-size', 'inherit')`. Turning that into a user script is left as an exercise for now.

Comment: [This has now been brought up on Code Review.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1905/42856)

Comment: @Mast point is still ongoing. It is an old feature request, is it going to be closed?

Comment: It looks like this was lost in the latest redesign, yeah?

Comment: @ale Yep, looks like it.